# Editing an Excel Pivot table using perl

Tags: excel, perl, pivot-table, xlsx

I have an excel 2010 file (xlsx) with a sheet of data and a sheet with pivot table using that data.
I would like to write a perl code that can change the data, and then the pivot table would be changed automaticly according to the new data.

I'm using perl packages:
`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Worksheet`
`Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser`
`Excel::Writer::XLSX`
`Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`

How can I do it?
Do I need another package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [DBD:CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-CSV/) and [DBIx:SQLCrosstab](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-SQLCrosstab/SQLCrosstab.pm):

**References**

- [Generating Database Server-Side Cross Tabulations](http://www.onlamp.com/2003/12/04/crosstabs.html#using_dbix::sqlcrosstab)
- [Import File into MySQL](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=263124)
- [Excel Spreadsheet Data Set](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=106188)